# How many dictatorships governments does the US currently support?

Tags: united-states, form-of-government, dictatorship

How many dictatorship governments are there in the world currently and how many of them are supported by the US. It can be economic or military support.

Comment: "dictatorship" vs "non-dictatorship" is not so easy to define as it is not really a binary state.

Comment: What does "economic support" mean? Does providing humanitarian food aid to North Korea count as "economic support"?

Comment: A quick Google search showed https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_authoritarian_regimes_supported_by_the_United_States as first result

Comment: No humanitarian. I'm talking dictatorships like Iraq (with Saddam), Cuba (before Castro), Egypt, etc...

Comment: @luweiqi, wow that list of authoritarian governments US still supports is really scary considering they have been a big advocate for `democracy`

Comment: @luweiqi And now this question is rising to the top. I think that's a win for Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has an up to date [List of authoritarian regimes supported by the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_authoritarian_regimes_supported_by_the_United_States). As of this writing, there are 22 authoritarian regimes that are supported by the United States, primarily in the Middle East and Africa.

Note that this list includes many countries that are constitutionally a democracy, but one candidate or party has ruled unopposed for an extended period of time, such as Nursultan Äbishuly Nazarbayev of Kazakhstan (since 1989) and the People's Action Party of Singapore (since 1959). Thus it's not correct to say that these are dictatorships, since the ruling party could be democratically voted out of office, but the odds of it happening in practice are unlikely.